# Real analyticity of harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $u(x,y)$ be harmonic on a domain $D \in \mathbb C$, Can we say that $f(x)=u(x,0)$ is real analytic on $D \cap \mathbb R$ if it is non-empty?

Clearly $f$ is infinitely differentiable on the domain, But what about analyticity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's true. One way to see this is to show that there exists (locally) a conjugate harmonic function $v$ such that $u+iv$ is holomorphic. This is shown in text books on harmonic maps or elliptic PDE of second order.

Another way is to find an integral representation for $u$ (again, it suffices to do that locally. Googling will find you resources for this, e.g. [this one](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/teaching/m435s14/PotentialTheory.pdf)) and to note that the integral kernel admits a represention by it's Taylor series.